# JQuery clear all rows after the first row?

Tags: jquery

Given the follow:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr> </tr>
  <tr> </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

I can clear the table by doing: `$("myTable").html("");`

But, I'd like to instead clear all rows but the first one.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$('#myTable tr:gt(0)').remove()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to remove all rows except for table header so why don't you create th as

```
<table id='my Table'>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And Jquery as

```
 $('#myTable tr td').parents('tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution less elegant:

```
$('#myTable tr').not($('#myTable tr:first')).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit inelegant:

```
$("#myTable").slice(1, 4).remove();
```